# Ajax Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-rest-framework

Hello before i am currently facing an issue where im getting lots of Ajax Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined.

here is my ajax call :

```
endpoint = 'api/chart/data'
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: endpoint,    
  success: function(data){
    window.conversion_label = data.conversion_datarsion_label
    window.conversion_data= data.conversion_data
    window.profit_data_per_project= data.profit_data_per_project
    window.project_complete_date = data.sales_project_time



//revi_sum is the monthly sum of the rev
    window.revi_sum = []
    window.revi_month = []
//revi_month is the month of which the rev are made
    window.sales_revi = data.sales_rev_per_month
    for(i=0 ; i <= sales_revi.length  ; i++){
        revi_sum.push(sales_revi[i].sum)
        revi_month.push(moment().month(sales_revi[i].month - 1).format("MMMM"))}

    console.log(sales_revi)
    console.log(revi_month)
    console.log(revi_sum)

//this is the monthly quota 
    window.sales_revi_quota = []
    window.sales_revi_quota_month = []
    window.sales_quota = data.sales_rev_quota
    for(i=0 ; i < sales_quota.length ; i++){
        sales_revi_quota.push(sales_quota[i].sales_rev_quota)
        sales_revi_quota_month.push(moment().month(sales_quota[i].sales_rev_quota_date).format("MMMM"))}

//this is the dates of which each project created. use for tracking profit 
    window.sales_project_date = []
    for(i=0 ; i < project_complete_date.length ; i++){
        sales_project_date.push(new Date(project_complete_date[i]))}



    createChart()


},
error: function(error_data){
console.log('error')
console.log(error_data)
}
})
```

i do not understand why im getting this issue when im doing my loops within the ajax call itself , anyhelp will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which line is causing the error, and which property is it saying it can't read?

Comment: It's probably this line:  i <= sales_revi.length. You need to make it i < sales_revi.length, otherwise i takes a value that equals to sales_revi.length, and there's no element by that index. Then it tries to read a property on undefined, and that's why you get and error.

Comment: Also, I see other problems with this code. One of them is global variables. They can be easily changed from anywhere within the application, breaking the intended behavior. Your variables get initialized in async code, so you can't also tell exactly when they will be initialized. The other problem is for loops. You need to use let to initialize the increment, like this: for(let i = 0; ...). Otherwise, you create yet another global variable that can mess with other loops in the same scope. If you can't use let, use var, but then each increment variable should have a unique name (i, j, k, ...)